# Creating open source project for Android

Tags: android, open-source, repository

I want to create an open source application for Android that will be available through a repository control version system. The problem is pretty fundamental, I need a tutorial that will cover the basics of licensing & how to properly maintain and create open source project (application).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, find a proper license that suits for your needs.

Maybe you can begin with this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license and then dig into the different Opensource licenses : there are a lot.

http://www.github.com is a good challenger to host opensource projects. The help is great if you need to learn Git.
You will be the owner of the project and you will be able to accept or refuse contributions. Later, you will be able to give more rights to trusted buddies that will help you building the software (because when success rise, you won't be able to handle all the submissions).

I suggest you create an empty project and pratice on it, alone.
You can delete it when you feel enough comfortable with the interface, actions to do, etc...

Do not start directly with your final project.
You will make mistakes, better to do them on a dummy project.

Good luck :)